# An elegant and fast way to consecutively iterate over two or more containers in Python?

Tags: python, iterator

I have three collection.deques and what I need to do is to iterate over each of them and perform the same action:

```
for obj in deque1:  
    some_action(obj)  

for obj in deque2:  
    some_action(obj)

for obj in deque3:  
    some_action(obj)
```

I'm looking for some function XXX which would ideally allow me to write:

```
for obj in XXX(deque1, deque2, deque3):  
    some_action(obj)
```

The important thing here is that XXX have to be efficient enough - without making copy or silently using range(), etc. I was expecting to find it in built-in functions, but I found nothing similar to it so far.

Is there such thing already in Python or I have to write a function for that by myself?

Comment: Have you looked at the zip function?

Comment: AFAIK the zip() function is not what I need here.

Comment: The subject didn't make sense to me so I changed "consequently" into "consecutively". Please rollback if I'm just ignorant!

Comment: Thanks, David, that does make sense

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Depending on what order you want to process the items:

```
import itertools

for items in itertools.izip(deque1, deque2, deque3):
    for item in items:
        some_action(item)

for item in itertools.chain(deque1, deque2, deque3):
    some_action(item)
```

I'd recommend doing this to avoid hard-coding the actual deques or number of deques:

```
deques = [deque1, deque2, deque3]
for item in itertools.chain(*deques):
    some_action(item)
```

To demonstrate the difference in order of the above methods:

```
>>> a = range(5)
>>> b = range(5)
>>> c = range(5)
>>> d = [a, b, c]
>>>
>>> for items in itertools.izip(*d):
...     for item in items:
...         print item,
...
0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4
>>>
>>> for item in itertools.chain(*d):
...     print item,
...
0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4
>>>
```

Answer (score 21):

The answer is in [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)

> ```
> itertools.chain(*iterables)
> ```
>
> Make an iterator that returns elements from the first iterable until
>   it is exhausted, then proceeds to the
>   next iterable, until all of the
>   iterables are exhausted. Used for
>   treating consecutive sequences as a
>   single sequence. Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def chain(*iterables):
>     # chain('ABC', 'DEF') --> A B C D E F
>     for it in iterables:
>         for element in it:
>             yield element
> ```

Answer (score 9):

Call me crazy, but why is using itertools thought to be necessary? What's wrong with:

```
def perform_func_on_each_object_in_each_of_multiple_containers(func, containers):
    for container in containers:
        for obj in container:
            func(obj)

perform_func_on_each_object_in_each_of_multiple_containers(some_action, (deque1, deque2, deque3)
```

Even crazier: you probably are going to use this once. Why not just do:

```
for d in (deque1, deque2, deque3):
    for obj in d:
        some_action(obj)
```

What's going on there is immediately obvious without having to look at the code/docs for the long-name function or having to look up the docs for itertools.something()

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? This is something that comes up a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Use `itertools.chain(deque1, deque2, deque3)`

Answer (score 3):

How about zip?

```
for obj in zip(deque1, deque2, deque3):
    for sub_obj in obj:
        some_action(sub_obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Accepts a bunch of iterables, and yields the contents for each of them in sequence.

```
def XXX(*lists):
   for aList in lists:
      for item in aList:
         yield item



l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l3 = [1.0, 1.1, 1.2]

for item in XXX(l1, l2, l3):
   print item

1
2
3
4
a
b
c
1.0
1.1
1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want i[tertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

"Make an iterator that returns elements from the first iterable until it is exhausted, then proceeds to the next iterable, until all of the iterables are exhausted. Used for treating consecutive sequences as a single sequence."

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then you can use `map` with the first argument set to None, and all the other arguments as your lists to iterate over.

E.g (from an iPython prompt, but you get the idea):

```
In [85]: p = [1,2,3,4]

In [86]: q = ['a','b','c','d']

In [87]: f = ['Hi', 'there', 'world', '.']

In [88]: for i,j,k in map(None, p,q,f):
   ....:     print i,j,k
   ....:
   ....:
1 a Hi
2 b there
3 c world
4 d .
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do this :

```
for obj in deque1 + deque2 + deque3:  
some_action(obj)
```

Comment: But then you're concatting those lists into a megalist. That's a giant time-drain.

Answer (score -2):

```
>>> a = [[],[],[]]
>>> b = [[],[],[]]
>>> for c in [*a,*b]:
    c.append("derp")

    
>>> a
[['derp'], ['derp'], ['derp']]
>>> b
[['derp'], ['derp'], ['derp']]
>>>
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation to your answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)